# How do I grab meta data from an HTML file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, preg-match, file-get-contents, str-replace

I am trying to create a feature on my website where users can upload links, like Digg. I have code that grabs the HTML source code from the URL that a user uploads to my website, and stores it in a .txt file. Then I want to grab the contents in the tag

```
<meta name="content" description="GRAB THIS">
```

assuming this tag exists. Sometimes it works, but other times it doesn't work, even though the source code for that particular webpage contains the necessary meta tag exactly as I have specified in my code. I've noticed that it seems to not work correctly if the "GRAB THIS" content contain html entities (&, etc.). Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to get this to work. Here is my code:

```
$html_data = file_get_contents( $path_to_txt_file_that_contains_html );
preg_match( '#<meta name="description" content="(.+?)">#si', $html_data, $tor;
$tor = str_replace ( '<meta name="description" content="' , "", $tor[0] );
$tor = str_replace ( '">', "", $tor );
```

Sometimes $tor still contains

```
<meta name="description" content="CONTENT"
```

but without the closing >, so my code breaks once I put this in a mySQl database. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: You're using a regex on HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually extremely simple.

PHP offers it's own built in solution: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I searched for about an hour and never saw this one.

Comment: Yeah np. I guess it's what you search for since i found it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Most people will tell you to use DomDocument for parsing html. Although i agree in most situations, sometimes it's just plain easier to use regex. So since you are using regex in your question, here is a regex solution.

```
$html_data = file_get_contents( $path_to_txt_file_that_contains_html );
preg_match( '#<meta name="description".*content="([^"]+)">#siU', $html_data, $tor);
$tor = $tor[1];
```

That's untested but should work just fine in your situation.